# Regex: Extracting numbers from parentheses with multiple matches

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, parentheses

How do I match the year such that it is general for the following examples.

```
a <- '"You Are There" (1953) {The Death of Socrates (399 B.C.) (#1.14)}'
b <- 'Þegar það gerist (1998/I) (TV)'
```

I have tried the following, but did not have the biggest success.

```
gsub('.+\\(([0-9]+.+\\)).?$', '\\1', a)
```

What I thought it did was to go until it finds a (, then it would make a group of numbers, then any character until it meets a ). And if there are several matches, I want to extract the first group.

Any suggestions to where I go wrong? I have been doing this in R.

Comment: So, expected matches are `1953` and `1998`? Try `sub("^.*?\\((\\d{4})[^)]*\\).*", "\\1", a)`

Comment: Yes, sorry for not pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern contains `.+` parts that match 1 or more chars as many as possible, and at best your pattern could grab last 4 digit chunks from the incoming strings.

You may use

```
^.*?\((\d{4})(?:/[^)]*)?\).*
```

Replace with `\1` to only keep the 4 digit number. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hn6OW2/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\(` - a `(`
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1: four digits
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

  - `/` - a `/`
  - `[^)]*` - any 0+ chars other than `)`
- `)?` - end of the group
- `\)` - a `)`                          (OPTIONAL, MAY BE OMITTED)
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/DCRdGM):

```
a <- c('"You Are There" (1953) {The Death of Socrates (399 B.C.) (#1.14)}', 'Þegar það gerist (1998/I) (TV)', 'Johannes Passion, BWV. 245 (1725 Version) (1996) (V)')
sub("^.*?\\((\\d{4})(?:/[^)]*)?\\).*", "\\1", a) 
# => [1] "1953" "1998" "1996"
```

Another base R solution is to match the 4 digits after `(`:

```
regmatches(a, regexpr("\\(\\K\\d{4}(?=(?:/[^)]*)?\\))", a, perl=TRUE))
# => [1] "1953" "1998" "1996"
```

The `\(\K\d{4}` pattern matches `(` and then drops it due to `\K` match reset operator and then a `(?=(?:/[^)]*)?\\))` lookahead ensures there is an optional `/` + 0+ chars other than `)` and then a `)`. Note that `regexpr` extracts the first match only.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I will check the answered in 5 minutes when available.

Comment: Is there a way to capturing the correct year in 'Johannes Passion, BWV. 245 (1725 Version) (1996) (V)' also? Here it captures the "1725" rather than 1996.

Comment: You should be more specific about the pattern then. *a (, then it would make a group of numbers, then any character until it meets a )*  does not cover this one.

Comment: Ah, it is because I am working with the dataset right now, and after extracting years using your suggestion, I just notices a few datapoints with unexpected years. It wasn't until right now I rand into this new format.

Comment: Check [`^.*?\((\d{4})(?:/[^)]*|\s*(?:A\.?D|B\.?C)?)\).*`](https://regex101.com/r/hn6OW2/2) Or maybe [`^.*?\((\d{4})(?:/[^)]*)?\).*`](https://regex101.com/r/hn6OW2/3) is enough

Comment: Holy moly, that is a wild regex! Thanks, I will try it out :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c('"You Are There" (1953) {The Death of Socrates (399 B.C.) (#1.14)}', 'Þegar það gerist (1998/I) (TV)')

years <- str_match(strings, "\\((\\d+(?: B\\.C\\.)?)")[,2]
years
# [1] "1953" "1998"
```

The expression here is

```
\(               # (
(\d+             # capture 1+ digits
    (?: B\.C\.)? # B.C. eventually
)
```

Note that backslashes need to be escaped in `R`.

Comment: If you want to define the eras, it may make more sense to also add a `A.D.` alternative.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: As seen in the comments to your question it might not yet be clear what OP really wants, so I leave it as it is.